# Two lines with link and span in h1 tag

Tags: html

I have a shopify store, in the first line of my title of the product, I have an internal link to the vendor page, in the second line there is the product title. 
I read it's valid to put two lines with `<br/>` in an `<h1>` heading (in order not to use two h1 headings), but I want to combine it with an `<a>` link (1st line) and a `<span>` (2nd line) for different styling.
Is it valid what I'm doing, also in terms of SEO? Thank you for helping!!

```
<h1><a class="product-vendor-hyperlink" href="/collections/{{product.vendor | handleize}}">{{ product.vendor }}</a><br/><span class="product-single__title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</span></h1>
```

Comment: I agree with the display: block solution as provided by @Jon P - but question the basic premise. a H1 is the main heading of the page and is intended to provide a high level heading as the the fundamental nature of the content on your page. As such - the h1 should really only contain the text content to achieve that. To add a link into the h1 muddies its semantic purpose and IMO should not be done. Yes - it is valid html to do that - but you should look at what the h1 heading isactually intended to do in the page. A link to the vendor really has no place in a h1 heading.... again IMO

Comment: I thought I can prevent from mentioning the vendor twice, in the h1 as heading and additionally as a link in the body. And I could make the link to the vendor in a prominent position. Do you think in terms of SEO a link in an h1 heading is crap? Then I change the whole thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid, but not needed. Instead you can get rid of the `br` entirely. Set one or both of your child nodes to `display:block`

```css
.product-vendor-hyperlink{display:block;}
```

```html
<h1><a class="product-vendor-hyperlink" href="/collections/{{product.vendor | handleize}}">{{ product.vendor }}</a><span class="product-single__title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</span></h1>
```

Another option is to consider the use of the `<header>` tag if you want to give full `h1` weight to the product title but still keep the vendor link associated with being in the header. You can use this at the page level or use `sections` , `div` etc, but NOT `li`.

```html
<header>  
  <a class="product-vendor-hyperlink" href="/collections/{{product.vendor | handleize}}">{{ product.vendor }}</a>
  <h1 class="product-single__title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! I appreciate your answer!! And it's not a problem like this for SEO? Search engines would just read "[vendor] [title]"? Or would you recommend another way, like h1 for product title and h2 for product vendor? Thank you!!!

Comment: If you want [Vendor][Title] will be considered as the contents of the H1 tag. If that is what you want, then that's fine

Answer (score 1):

Its valid, but its really bad in terms of SEO, use the heading hierarchy and semantic HTML5 tags instead, check the two resources below:

[Semantic tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)

[Heading Hierarchy](https://yoast.com/how-to-use-headings-on-your-site/)

Comment: Thank you for the links!! Very interesting articles! The thing is that vendor and product title are both very important, both on the same top level. I just separated them because I wanted to make a link to the vendor collection internally (all products of the vendor I sell). I still study your article though...

Comment: Any time @Simonski, btw you could use the H1 tags with different style, it gives the same result styling with improving of your SEO page.

Comment: Great!! That's what I did actually, The vendor in the first line is smaller and with underline to make the link more dominant, the product title is in large letters (if this is what you meant)? Two different stylings in the same h1 heading. Actually I really like the solution, but i just hope I won't get SEO minus for that...

Comment: Try many solution and check your SEO and Audit, there is many tool on the market.